# No indication of the subfigures in the list of figures

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I changed my document from subfig to subcaption, since I rode, it results in problems together with hyperref (it doesn't show any problems - yet, that's what wonders me).
I'd like to change the caption of the subfigures to
' a) High count' without showing the subfigures in the list of figures.
The star does remove the line in list of figures, but the a) disappears.
I couldn't find any helpful comment, does someone have an idea?

Here is a short version of my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.5cm, hmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm},vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{upgreek}  %for not italic greek letter
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true, font=large,font=bf, labelfont=bf, labelformat=simple, position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lscape} % gedrehte tabellen
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor= black, pdfborder={0 0 0},bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \caption*{High count}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graphiken/Evaluation_calib/Calib_5s-120s_218_440}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \caption*{Low count}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graphiken/Evaluation_calib/Calib_120-5_218}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{A figure with two subfigures using SUBCAPTION}
    \label{TS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: IIRC, figures are level 1 (sections) and subfigures are level 2 (subsections), so `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` should not print subfigures in the LOF.  Make the change after the TOC.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about). It helps keep the site clean, it doesn't matter which one :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Load the `subcaption` package with no options and then use (explored more in the [`subcaption` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)):

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{ending}{#2)}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=ending,font=large,font=bf, labelfont=bf, position=top}
```

to get your custom format from your question `a) High count`. The option `list=true` puts in the LOF so that option has been removed too. Code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{ending}{#2)}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=ending,font=large,font=bf, labelfont=bf, position=top}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \caption{High count}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\linewidth}
    \caption{Low count}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{A figure with two subfigures using SUBCAPTION}
    \label{TS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note: thank you for including code in your first question! Just some tips, if the package isn't necessary for the question such as `amsmath` it doesn't need to be included. Same goes for options such as `colorlinks` in `hyperref` and the `\documentclass[options]{report}`, the minimal code necessary is sufficient. Instead of figures that we do not have access to, you can use `example-image-a` from the `graphicx` package. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: thank You for all the hints.
The addition with the example image is helpful!
I'm sorry, I checked the caption manual, but I couldn't figure out the 'ending' labelformat in the comment \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{ending}{#2)}. What does it define exactly?

Comment: In your question, it said you wanted the subfigure caption to be like `a) High count`, as in one bracket `a)`. That is how you define a custom format for the subfigure caption with `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`. If you wanted it to be like `(a)` then just use `labelformat=parens` in either loading `subcaption` or in the `\captionsetup` settings

Comment: Ah, I see, but this one bracket can be defined with labelformat=brace as well, right?

Comment: I was unaware of that to be honest, all of the options are not spelt in the documentation. I just added a workaround, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I would like to change the numbering to
A High Count
I would use 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,font=large,font=bf, labelfont=bf, position=top}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure})}
But this option does not work. The numbering is in capital letters, but I still have the right bracket.

Comment: It does work, if you remove the `)` in your \renewcommand: `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [`subcaption`-documentation](https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) carefully (e.g. page 3 footnote), you will see that the option `list=true` is responsible for that. Just remove it from the package options, and you will get your desired result.

BTW: You can choose the width of your subfigures to be `0.5\linewidth` if you comment the line break between your subfigures, which inserts a space and therefore causes the line break in your PDF:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
   \caption{High count}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
   \caption{Low count}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}%
```

Comment: Thank You for the hints! It really helped me and fixed my problem!